# Warning: imagedestroy(): 7 is not a valid Image resource

Tags: php, oop, gd

I have a class. Something like this:

```
class graphic{
 private $image;
 private $width;
 private $height;
 function __construct(...){
  $this->image=imagecreatetruecolor(...);
 }
 ...
 function resize($width,$height){
  $temp=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
  imagecopyresampled($temp,$this->image,
   0,0,0,0,
   $width,$height,
   $this->width,$this->height
  );
  $this->image=$temp;
  imagedestroy($temp);
  ...
 }
}
```

I do same thing i always used to do when i needed to create a resized image. Only difference is now I'm trying to do that in class. Here's what I do:

I have an image in class field. I'm creating a temporary image, into which I copy resampled image from class field. Then I replace class field contents with my temporary image contents using simple "=" assignment. Then, when I try to remove my temporary image i get a warning:

```
Warning: imagedestroy(): 7 is not a valid Image resourceWarning: imagedestroy(): 7 is not a valid Image resource
```

vardumping that temp-image variable gives that variable is "resource(7) of type (gd)"

What am I doing wrong and why does that warning occur?

Comment: Why are you doing `$this->image=$temp;` and then destroying the image?

Comment: @silkfire I think he wanted to release the reference. @Andrienko If that's the case, you should only do `unset($temp);`. You should only destroy the image in the [__destruct](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) magic method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> $this->image=$temp;
> imagedestroy($temp);
> ```

Wrong order, and wrong operation.

```
imagedestroy($this->image);
$this->image=$temp;
```